# JdbcTemplate binding to multiple datasources

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, jdbctemplate, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to add a second data-source to a spring Boot project.

The primary connection is configured using `spring.datasource.*` properties, which I are getting configured using `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`. The entire project makes use of `JdbcTemplate` and no JPA config is required.

If I am creating an `@Configuration` for secondary datasource and excluding default datasource injected packages, the secondary configuration is overriding the default datasource which will be configured using datasourceautoconfiguration class

Is what I am trying to do possible?

I tried building both datasources seperately and autowiring the JdbcTemplate based on qualifier -> This works.

I tried only binding the second datatsource and autowired using qualifier -> this takes second datasource for the primary jdbcTemplate as well. Since first source is configured using DataSourceAutoConfiguration, I am uanble to bind this source to a template.

P.S: sorry I cannot paste the code here and default config should be untouched.

Comment: As soon as you add a second datasource the autoconfiguration will stop working as it assumes you want full control. You will need to add both configuration manually. This is also explained in the Spring Boot Reference Guide.

Comment: M.Deinum thanks for the reply. Yes, as soon as I added the second config, the JdbcTemplate was pointing to secondary source. No matter if I used @Qualifier or ExcludeFilter on the config. 

The idea was to not disturb existing config. as we are not sure how it will impact the project. Could you please share the link of reference guide?

Answer (score 0):

I could not achieve the above requirement using `@Configuration` but the alternative solution what I did was, build the `DataSource` in a `@Service` and bind that to the local JdbcTemplate where I wanted to use that secondary connection

Edit: As per @M.Deniums' suggestion in the comment, this should not be done.

Comment: Don't do that.... Don't recreate the datasource because you need to or swap out the one in the `JdbcTemplate`. That is a very bad idea and will horribly fail under load. Instead use proper configuration, as stated in the reference guide -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-two-datasources. Create one using the regular `spring.datasource` namespace and the other using yuor own.